# About the loss of infer type in Record<infer K, infer V>

Tags: typescript

```
type Foo<T extends Record<string, string>> = T extends Record<infer K, infer V> ? Record<V & string, K> : never;

type FooResult = Foo<{ "key": "value" }>;
```

I'm new to TS, can someone explain the following for me ?

> Why is the V in Record<infer K, infer V> not the string type after the constrained `Record<string, string>`?

Comment: I don't understand your question - what do you expect `ReverseKeyValue<{ "key": "value" }>` to be?

Comment: They mean that they had to intersect `V` with `string` in the truthy part of the conditional. Since `T` is  `Record<string, string>` it is expected that `V` is inferred as `string`, but this is not what happens. An alternative to intersection is to `infer V extends string`. As for why TS does not do this kind narrowing, I don't know. It is pretty often at the type level that TS "forgets" context like that

Comment: It seems more likely that you want something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrDeoW) instead: the existing type will produce a record with the union of all keys at each value. At any rate, with what runtime code is that type used?

Comment: I'm going to [edit] the question so that it's not called `ReverseKeyValue`.  As jsejcksn said, the type function you wrote wouldn't do the right thing for most cases; you'd probably want `ReverseKeyValue<{a: "x", b: "y"}>` to be `{x: "a", y: "b"}` and not `{x: "a" | "b", y: "a" | "b"}`... but your question really isn't about how to reverse keys and values but why constraints are lost on `infer`red type parameters.  So the whole "key-value reverse" thing is distracting from your question.  If it's a big deal let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a missing feature of TypeScript; currently when you [`infer` in a conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), the new type parameter doesn't get the same constraints as the type from which it is inferred.  So in

```
type Foo<T extends Record<string, string>> =
  T extends Record<infer K, infer V> ? Record<V, K> : never;
```

the `V` type parameter does not inherit the `string` constraint, and you get an error.

---

There is an open feature request to do better here at [microsoft/TypeScript#51108](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51108); if you're interested in seeing this implemented it wouldn't hurt to go to that issue and give it a .  (It probably wouldn't help very much either, but it wouldn't hurt.)

---

For now you just have to work around it, either by the intersection as shown in your example:

```
type Foo<T extends Record<string, string>> =
  T extends Record<infer K, infer V> ? Record<V & string, K> : never;
```

or you could add an [`extends` constraint on the `infer` type variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables) as follows:

```
type Foo<T extends Record<string, string>> =
  T extends Record<infer K, infer V extends string> ? Record<V, K> : never;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZygCUIBjOAJ10X2AoEtsBzAGiloeYD4uoBeAFBQoqDFjyES5KokYAzCBSgBpNvMVQAamkw4C7Ooya8A-MTKVqmtst4AuKNggA3RQG4BA0JFgIS+AFcAG2B+XyQAbygAIgBrCBBoh2jnAEMggIhoqABfLjcgA)

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer,I'm sorry my naming made you misunderstood,sorry for replying to you now 